# how to explain in a statistical way, if revenue increase in several store but overall no change

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

Let's say, Target has implemented a new store management methodology and applied to 100 stores went well as revenue increase. but once extend to all 1000 stores not seeing the lift of revenue.

How to analyze/explain this in a statistical way?
I was thinking about this is kinda a quasi-experiment based on the different time intervals.
first, the revenue increase might not be significant.
second, the interrupted time series usually have concerns that the two different time interval will introduce temporal variant. so the treatment and control are not independent.

What is a good comprehensive way to explain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know your particular numbers, but you may have encountered an example of *Simpson's paradoxon*. Arithmetically, it boils down to the observation that
$$\frac{s_{11}}{n_{11}} < \frac{s_{21}}{n_{21}} \quad\mbox{and}\quad \frac{s_{12}}{n_{12}} < \frac{s_{22}}{n_{22}}$$
does generally *not* imply
$$\frac{s_{11} + s_{12}}{n_{11}+n_{12}} < \frac{s_{21} + s_{22}}{n_{21}+n_{22}}$$
For examples and a detailed discussion, see

> Wang B, Wu P, Kwan B, Tu XM, Feng C.: ["Simpson's Paradox: Examples."](https://dx.doi.org/10.11919%2Fj.issn.1002-0829.218026) Shanghai Arch Psychiatry. 2018;30(2):139-143.

Comment: You are right. but there is no specific number in this question. I just ask how could we explain this problem more reasonable way. I think if the question is like this: among the 1000 stores, we are seeing all the regions revenue increase, but revenue overall doesn't. this is definitely a simpson's praradox example. but for the origin question I ask, this might not be a proper direction?